# Invalid table name without using a reserved word?

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I'm creating a table using Oracle SQL, and when trying to create a table called 'Card' I keep getting the error that it's an invalid table name. Here's my code:

```
CREATE TABLE Card
(
CardNumber varchar2(20) Not Null,
CardType varchar2(5) Not Null,
CONSTRAINT CustomerIDForeignKey FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES (Customer),
CONSTRAINT CardTypeConstraint CHECK (CardType='Credit' or CardType='Debit' or CardType='Gift')
)
```

And here's the error code I'm getting:

> ```
> Error starting at line : 1 in command -
> CREATE TABLE Card
> (
> CardNumber varchar2(20) Not Null,
> CardType varchar2(5) Not Null,
> CONSTRAINT CustomerIDForeignKey FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES (Customer),
> CONSTRAINT CardTypeConstraint CHECK (CardType='Credit' or CardType='Debit' or CardType='Gift')
> )
> ```
>
> Error report -
>       SQL Error: ORA-00903: invalid table name
>       00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
>       *Cause:
>       *Action:

Any help would be appreciated! I didn't find 'Card' on the [list of Oracle SQL's reserved words](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621), so I'm not sure what the issue is. Thank you!

Comment: Not error but `CONSTRAINT CardTypeConstraint CHECK CardType IN ('Credit', 'Debit' ,'Gift')`

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks! I'm a complete beginner to databases and still learning :-)

Comment: When you try to add a simple table with that name you will notice it works. So the table name problem is somewhere else. The FK constraint you have is the only other place where a table name is used (and actually missing).

Comment: I suggest normalizing this by having a cardType table and having your foreign key constraint to that table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add column `CustomerId` to `Card` table and change refrences to `table_name(column_name)`:

**[SqlFiddleDEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5c479/1/0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(CustomerID INT PRIMARY KEY);


CREATE TABLE Card(
 CardNumber varchar2(20) Not Null,
 CardType varchar2(5) Not Null,
 CustomerId INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CustomerIDForeignKey FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerId),
CONSTRAINT CardTypeConstraint CHECK (CardType IN ('Credit', 'Debit' ,'Gift'))
);
```

Also you can replace:

```
CHECK (CardType='Credit' or CardType='Debit' or CardType='Gift')
```

with:

```
CHECK (CardType IN ('Credit', 'Debit' ,'Gift'))
```

You can think about:

1. Adding Primary Key to Card table
2. Hashing/encrypting card number (do not store as plain text)
3. Creating CreditCardType dictionary table